# Integral of rational function with a squared term in the denominator

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I know the integration when in the reciprocal there's only degree $1$, but what about degree $2$?
Take an example, $$\int\frac{x \, \mathrm{d}x}{a+bx^2}$$

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ constants? or functions of $x$?

Comment: Yes, they are constants

Comment: Do u-substitution with $u=a + bx^2$

Comment: Try a $u$ substitution with $u=a+bx^2$ then $du=2bx dx$ or $\frac{1}{2b}du = xdx$.

Comment: In the future, refrain from MathJax only titles.

Answer (score 4):

For this, put $v=a+bx^{2}$ then $dv = 2bxdx$ from which
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \frac{xdx}{a+bx^{2}} &=& \frac{1}{2b}\int \frac{1}{v}dv \\
                          &=& \frac{1}{2b}\ln | v |+ c \\
                          &=& \frac{1}{2b}\ln |a+bx^{2}|+c \\
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Sorry, I gave mistyped the question a bit,  here's the actual one

Comment: Ok I'lll edit toi reflect new situ

Comment: Quick comment. It should be $\ln|v|$ not $\ln (v)$.

Comment: @avid19 Good point, I'll re-edit to reflect requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{xdx}{a+bx^2}=\frac1{2b}\int\frac{2bxdx}{a+bx^2}=\frac1{2b}\int\frac{d(a+bx^2)}{a+bx^2}=\frac1{2b}\ln(a+bx^2)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = a+bx^2$ so that $\mathrm{d}u =2bx \, \mathrm{d}x \implies {\color{blue}{x \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2b} \, \mathrm{d}u}}$. Then our integral becomes $$\int \frac{\color{blue}{x \, \mathrm{d}x}}{a+bx^2}  = \frac{1}{2b}\int \frac{1}{u} \, \mathrm{d}u$$

This evaluates to $$\frac{1}{2b} \ln |u| + \mathrm{C} = \frac{1}{2b} \ln |a+bx^2| + \mathrm{C}$$